# How do I turn off the inbox for lifehacks inbox?

Tags: support

I'd like to turn off the inbox messages for comments on my Lifehacks.SE posts as the red flag is distracting when I'm on other SE sites and it looks like my posts will be getting a lot of comments for awhile.

How to do it?

Comment: @Phlume http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/global-inbox/info.

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. The only way is ask the team to delete your account there.